# F# take items from a sequence

Tags: f#, sequence, take

Im trying to learn F#

What I would like to do is download a webpage, split it into a sequence then find the index of an item and take the next 3 items after it.

Heres the code -- can someone show me what Im doing wrong please?

```
let find = "<head>"
let page = downloadUrl("http://www.stackoverflow.com")
let lines = seq (  page.Replace("\r", System.String.Empty).Split([|"\n"|],   StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)  )
let pos = lines |> Seq.findIndex(fun a -> a == find) // getting a Exception of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' was thrown.
let result = // now to get the next 3 items
printfn "%A" (Seq.toList result);;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you are doing some F# text processing. Here are some possible problems:

1. After you downloaded the HTML page, you didn't do any preprocessing, say remove all HTML tags.
2. `page.Replace("\r", System.String.Empty).Split([|"\n"|]` is problematic because I guess you want to split the items/words out. This line only splits lines out.
3. `let pos = lines |> Seq.findIndex(fun a -> a == find)` change `==` to `=`. In F#, `=` is the boolean operator for comparison.
4. `let result = lines |> Seq.take pos` only takes the first `pos` items. You should skip these items and then take `pos` items as in:

.

```
lines
|> Seq.skip (pos+1)
|> Seq.take 3
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let result = lines |> Seq.take pos
```

This line skips everything before the found item, not takes the 3 items after it.

**EDIT:** `Seq.findIndex` fails if the item searched for doesn't exist. You want `Seq.tryFindIndex`:

```
match lines |> Seq.tryFindIndex(fun a -> a == find) with
| Some pos -> let result = // now to get the next 3 items
              printfn "%A" (Seq.toList result)
| None     -> ()
```

Comment: hi thanks -- should have left that line out really -- might edit it? -- its the line before where i want to get the index of the item thats causing the problem -

Comment: just removed it sorry for the confusion

Comment: thanks -- using a combo of both answers -- wish i could mark both answers as merged and accepted :)