# working on sequences with lagged operators

Tags: f#, seq

A machine is turning on and off.
`seqStartStop` is a `seq<DateTime*DateTime>` that collects the start and end time of the execution of the machine tasks.

I would like to produce the sequence of periods where the machine is idle. In order to do so, I would like to build a sequence of tuples `(beginIdle, endIdle)`.

- `beginIdle` corresponds to the stopping time of the machine during
  the previous cycle.
- `endIdle` corresponds to the start time of the    current production
  cycle.

In practice, I have to build `(beginIdle, endIdle)` by taking the second element of the tuple for `i-1` and the fist element of the following tuple `i`

I was wondering how I could get this task done without converting `seqStartStop` to an array and then looping through the array in an imperative fashion.

Another idea creating two copies of `seqStartStop`: one where the head is tail is removed, one where the head is removed (shifting backwards the elements); and then appying `map2`.
I could use `skip`and `take` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786454/f-take-items-from-a-sequence)

All these seem rather cumbersome. Is there something more straightforward 
In general, I was wondering how to execute calculations on elements with different lags in a sequence.

Comment: How will you calculate the `beginIdle` for the first period and `endIdle` for the last period?

Comment: or are there one fewer idle periods than the periods the machine is on, in which case we don't need to worry about it.

Comment: Good question. Yes, there are fewer idle periods that when the machine is operating. The idle periods are the periods between the working periods. Therefore, there is always one idle period less than the number of working periods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement this pretty easily with [`Seq.pairwise`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370361.aspx) and `Seq.map`:

```
let idleTimes (startStopTimes : seq<DateTime * DateTime>) =
    startStopTimes
    |> Seq.pairwise
    |> Seq.map (fun (_, stop) (start, _) ->
        stop, start)
```

As for the more general question of executing on sequences with different lag periods, you could implement that by using `Seq.skip` and `Seq.zip` to produce a combined sequence with whatever lag period you require.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of using `map2` with two copies of the sequence, one slightly shifted by taking the tail of the original sequence, is quite a standard one in functional programming, so I would recommend that route.

The `Seq.map2` function is fine with working with lists with different lengths - it just stops when you reach the end of the shorter list - so you don't need to chop the last element of the original copy.

One thing to be careful of is how your original `seq<DateTime*DateTime>` is calculated. It will be recalculated each time it is enumerated, so with the `map2` idea it will be calculated twice. If it's cheap to calculate and doesn't involve side-effects, this is fine. Otherwise, convert it to a list first with `List.ofSeq`.

You can still use `Seq.map2` on lists as a list is an `IEnumerable` (i.e. a `seq`). Don't use `List.map2` unless the lists are the same length though as it is more picky than `Seq.map2`.

Comment: Thanks for the overview. I think I will use two shifted copies of the sequence.